# Missing certificate GeoTrust DV SSL CA - G4

Tags: wget, curl, certificates

Got a new certificate, but wget and curl are not connecting anymore:

```
wget https://MYDOMAIN

ERROR: cannot verify MYDOMAINS's certificate, issued by ‘/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./OU=Domain Validated SSL/CN=GeoTrust DV SSL CA - G4’:
```

Checking shows only these files:

```
ls /etc/ssl/certs/GeoTrust_*

GeoTrust_Global_CA_2.pem                           GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem                             GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem  GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem
GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority.pem
GeoTrust_Universal_CA_2.pem
GeoTrust_Universal_CA.pem`
```

Do I need to wait for ubuntu to add the G4 certificate? Copying files myself sounds scary.

I already did the `update-ca-certificates --fresh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
 update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

is only useful if you previously copied the certificate to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`.

---

Steps:

1. [download](https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/) the .pem file you need. ([Here is the official download](https://knowledge.geotrust.com/support/knowledge-base/index?page=content&id=SO26453)).
2. copy the file over from your download location to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` using `sudo` but with the extension `.crt`. Example command (use the actual name instead of "filename"):

   sudo cp ~/Downloads/filename.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/filename.crt
3. run `update-ca-certificates`.

Comment: yeah, but geotrust does not offer it, only the ssl-tools page, so not sure it is a valid one :(

Comment: The 2nd link seems to correct name. And the txt file version seems valid.

Comment: still could be a scam, why would some random homepage already have the certificate when the company itself is not yet publishing it .. should maybe be moved to sceptics :)

Comment: Just got a reply from geotrust that it's valid, download link here: https://knowledge.geotrust.com/support/knowledge-base/index?page=content&id=SO26453

Comment: Oh that is pretty cool from them :D Ill edit the link into the q. Thanks for the rep :D